# wx.ListCtrl always display icon on Windows

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

I'm using wxPython's `wx.ListCtrl` to display a table. For each Column I'm using the `InsertImageStringItem` method to insert a new row and use `SetStringItem` to add other columns. In the `InsertImageStringItem` method, I'm using `-1` for the image index so it should not display any icon in the first column. This works perfect on Mac OS X. But on Windows, the first column always display the icon with image index 0.

Any one knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows native widget probably requires the image since you're telling it that you're going to insert one. If you don't want to insert images in the first column, then just use InsertStringItem instead.

**EDIT:**

According to Robin Dunn, creator of wxPython:

*On Windows the native ListView control has a "feature" that if you give
it an image list then it assumes that you are going to want to display
items with images, so it reserves the space for them automatically.  One
way to work around this is to shift everything one column to the right,
so the first column has nothing in it except for the space reserved for
the image.  Then you can just set that column's width to zero.*

Source: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-ListCtrl-and-its-image-list-td2315539.html

Comment: Actually, I was using the InsertStringItem at first. (I need to add icons in other columns). But it always shows the icon in the first column on Windows. I think it's using the index 0 by default, so I changed to use InsertImageStringItem and use -1 by hand. But it still shows the icon of index 0.

Comment: I added some further explanation to my answer taken from the wxPython users group